# ANDROID sqlite no such table

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been trying to create a DB with sqlite in my android project and don't understand why I get this msg error "no such table" :S i thought i was creating the DB good. Any help?

here's my code handler_sqlite class :

```
public class Handler_sqlite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public Handler_sqlite(Context ctx)
    {
        super ( ctx, "MiBase", null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db ) 
    {
        String query =  " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuarios ( user VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, password VARCHAR );" ;
        db.execSQL(query);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int version_ant, int version_post)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS usuarios");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertarReg(String user, String password)
    {
        ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
        valores.put("user", user);
        valores.put("password", password);
        this.getWritableDatabase().insert("usuarios",null,valores);

    }

    public void abrir()
    {
        this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void cerrar()
    {
        this.close();
    }

    public String leer_user ()
    {
        String columnas[]={"user","password"};
        Cursor c = this.getReadableDatabase().query("usuarios",columnas,null,null,null,null,null);
        int iu;
        iu = c.getColumnIndex("user");

        c.moveToLast();
        return c.getString(iu);
    }

    public String leer_password ()
    {
        String columnas[]={"user","password"};
        Cursor c = this.getReadableDatabase().query("usuarios",columnas,null,null,null,null,null);
        int ip;
        ip = c.getColumnIndex("password");

        c.moveToLast();
        return c.getString(ip);
    }

}
```

and my main code that references to the bd :

```
Handler_sqlite helper = new Handler_sqlite(this);
 helper.abrir();
helper.insertarReg(username,passw);
String username2 = helper.leer_user();
String password2 = helper.leer_password();
```

current error :

error inserting password = x user = y android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: usuarios, while compiling: INSERT INTO usuarios (password,user) Values (?,?);

thanks in advance.

Comment: if you make any change to the table in onCreate(), you need to increase the database version

Comment: can you post the stacktrace please? Also, try deleting `IF NOT EXISTS` from the table creation SQL statement.

Comment: what do you mean? i am creating the table only if not exists right?

Comment: emmanuel, i am kind of new in the programming / android world, what is the stacktrace ?

Comment: it is the place where you see the error. Copy and past it here (by here I mean in your question by editing it).

Comment: do you find something?

Answer (score 1):

The name of your database should contain the .db extension (i.e. MiBase.db) when you pass it to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the create table statement is correct ? (ie the exec doesn't throw any exceptions/errors/etc).

Does the DB actually exist ? If you adb shell and run-as your app, look in the db directory (name may change from version to version) and see if there is a usarios.sqlite file.

Are you sure no typos for the table name in all your code ? (ie use a constant instead of re-typing it all over)